# how to use library of native camera for android ndk?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I tried to load libcamera_client.so but I have problems. According to my Android.mk, it should create a folder called "include" with camera libraries, right?. But it doesn't create the folder, I cannot see it. When I use `#include <camera/Camera.h>` and `using namespace android;` I see:

```
fatal error: camera/Camera.h: No such file or directory

error: 'android' is not a namespace-name
```

Somebody, can help me?

Thank in advance.

My Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := camera_client-prebuild
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libcamera_client.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := test
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := test.cpp
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := camera_client-prebuild
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -ldl -lm 

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

UPDATE 1:

I am trying to write an app for a specific Android device, which using the camera with native code. I took compiled libraries (libcamera_client.so) from my device and I want to load camera's functions.

I tried to write `LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -ldl -lm -lcamera_client` and copy the include directory (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/android-4.1.2_r2.1/include) inside local jni folder. But when I compile, I see `jni/camera/Camera.h:20:26: fatal error: utils/Timers.h: No such file or directory`, the problem is that `camera.h` depends from other libraries that I have not copied in my local project. When I remove the line:

```
#include <camera/Camera.h>
```

I can see:

```
arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lcamera_client
```

Moreover, I changed my code from this:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := test
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := test.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -ldl -lm
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libcamera_client
LOCAL_C_INCLUDE := frameworks/av/include
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

but the problem remains that depends on other libraries which I have not in my local project

```
jni/camera/Camera.h:20:26: fatal error: utils/Timers.h: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using the full Android source tree for building, so I'm going to assume you're writing an app for a specific Android device. If you're not, please don't do this - libcamera_client is not part of any public API or the NDK, so using it is very fragile.  Since the library is an implementation detail, individual Android vendors may modify or replace it at will, and it may disappear/change in a future version of Android.

That aside, the full Android build already includes that library, so you just need to reference it. Remove the PREBUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY section entirely, it's not needed.
Then try adding the following to your test rules:

```
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libcamera_client
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := frameworks/av/include
```

Also, why are you building a shared library as a final product, instead of an executable? That's likely wrong, unless you're leaving out the final build rules for a test program.

Answer (score 0):

No, `LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES` will not create folders. You should point this `make` variable to the `include` directory from your local copy of the AOSP tree, e.g. from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/master/include/.

You probably need more include directories to provide all extra files that the C++ preprocessor will be looking for, e.g. `cutils`, `utils`, etc.

At any rate, using `$(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)` for `libcamera_cient.so` is not correct. This will result in deploying this shared library with your APK to any device you install this APK. You don't need this file in your APK: there should be `libcamera_client.so` in `/system/lib` directory on any device. More than that, you want to use the device-dependent version of this library, and not the one you deploy. Luckily, the system loader will prefer the system version of this library, and ignore the copy you deployed.

The flag that you are expected to use in your `Android.mk` is `LOCAL_LDLIBS`. With recent releases of NDK, using `-lcamera_client` will trigger a warning, because NDK expects only public libraries that are officially provided with NDK to be linked this way.

Regarding `using namespace android`, this error message will disappear as soon as the precompiler will find `camera/Camera.h` file.

Comment: may you provide .so file for 64bit  ('arm64-v8a' version) of this project?  it's contains just 32bit .so files. please help me. https://github.com/alexcohn/native-camera2

Comment: @BhunnuBaba: I don't recommend using this library beyond POC. It won't work on API>23. Also, it would be an entirely separate effort to build it for arm64, because it uses platform sources and headers.